# JSONString won't convert to JSONArray

Tags: android, json, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, android-json

I am attempting to send a string json of teams through Bluetooth to another android device.  For some reason the Serializer will load a small list of teams but a large list of teams causes this error:

```
01-21 13:21:30.584    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at character 990 of [{"teleStackDirection":0,"teleCoopSet":0,"autoTotes":0,"teleCoopStack":0,"autoProgs":0,"telePlatform":0,"teleStackTotes":0,"mechLitterPusher":false,"mechLitterInserter":false,"teamNum":0,"mechToteFeeder":false,"teleCarryTote":0,"autoPos":0,"autoMoveTote":false,"mechContainerFlipper":false,"teleHumanStation":0,"id":"6d1d1c80-d386-401c-91c7-3260fdb28a9b","autoMove":false,"telePickUpLitter":false,"autoContainers":0,"teleMoveLitter":false,"teleStackContainers":0,"mechContainerStepRemover":false,"telePlaceTote":0,"telePlaceLitter":0},{"teleStackDirection":0,"teleCoopSet":0,"autoTotes":0,"teleCoopStack":0,"autoProgs":0,"telePlatform":0,"teleStackTotes":0,"mechLitterPusher":false,"mechLitterInserter":false,"teamNum":1,"mechToteFeeder":false,"teleCarryTote":0,"autoPos":0,"autoMoveTote":false,"mechContainerFlipper":false,"teleHumanStation":0,"id":"e10f158f-7254-4bfb-85eb-eb402be790c3","autoMove":false,"telePickUpLitter":false,"autoContainers":0,"teleMoveLitter":false,"teleStackContain
    01-21 13:21:30.618    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value toPos" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.648    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value kContainers" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.656    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value lse of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.662    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value e of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.728    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value gs" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.734    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value gs" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.740    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value {"teleCoopSet":0,"teleStackDirection":0,"autoTotes":0,"autoProgs":0,"teleCoopStack":0,"mechLitterPusher":false,"teleStackTotes":0,"telePlatform":0,"mechLitterInserter":false,"teamNum":34,"mechToteFeeder":false,"autoMoveTote":false,"autoPos":0,"teleCarryTote":0,"mechContainerFlipper":false,"teleHumanStation":0,"id":"c2108315-2ea6-4cd5-8205-c845ae48739c","autoMove":false,"autoContainers":0,"telePickUpLitter":false,"teleStackContainers":0,"teleMoveLitter":false,"mechContainerStepRemover":false,"telePlaceLitter":0,"telePlaceTote":0} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.757    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value {"teleCoopSet":0,"teleStackDirection":0,"autoTotes":0,"autoProgs":0,"teleCoopStack":0,"mechLitterPusher":false,"teleStackTotes":0,"telePlatform":0,"mechLitterInserter":false,"teamNum":34,"mechToteFeeder":false,"autoMoveTote":false,"autoPos":0,"teleCarryTote":0,"mechContainerFlipper":false,"teleHumanStation":0,"id":"c2108315-2ea6-4cd5-8205-c845ae48739c","autoMove":false,"autoContainers":0,"telePickUpLitter":false,"teleStackContainers":0,"teleMoveLitter":false,"mechContainerStepRemover":false,"telePlaceLitter":0,"telePlaceTote":0} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.775    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value {"teleCoopSet":0,"teleStackDirection":0,"autoTotes":0,"autoProgs":0,"teleCoopStack":0,"mechLitterPusher":false,"teleStackTotes":0,"telePlatform":0,"mechLitterInserter":false,"teamNum":34,"mechToteFeeder":false,"autoMoveTote":false,"autoPos":0,"teleCarryTote":0,"mechContainerFlipper":false,"teleHumanStation":0,"id":"c2108315-2ea6-4cd5-8205-c845ae48739c","autoMove":false,"autoContainers":0,"telePickUpLitter":false,"teleStackContainers":0,"teleMoveLitter":false,"mechContainerStepRemover":false,"telePlaceLitter":0,"telePlaceTote":0} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.777    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value ners" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.781    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value lePickUpLitter" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.787    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value HumanStation" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.794    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value CarryTote" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.801    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value sher" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.807    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value teleCoopStack" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.866    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value chToteFeeder" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.873    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value ackTotes" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.879    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value oopSet" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.886    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value ver" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.894    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value tainers" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.900    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value tainers" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.904    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value tainers" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.905    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value tainers" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.908    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value tainers" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.909    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value tainers" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.911    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value tainers" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.912    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value tainers" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.914    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value tainers" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.915    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value tainers" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.916    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value tainers" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.958    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value eStackDirection" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.967    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value kUpLitter" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.974    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value Tote" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.981    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value oopStack" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.988    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value oopStack" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.992    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value oopStack" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.994    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value oopStack" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:30.995    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value oopStack" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:31.042    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value Flipper" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:31.048    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value Flipper" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:31.053    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value Flipper" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:31.055    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value Flipper" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:31.056    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value Flipper" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:31.058    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value Flipper" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:31.059    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value Flipper" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:31.063    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value Flipper" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:31.065    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value Flipper" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:31.123    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value rs" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:31.127    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value rs" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:31.133    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value rs" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:31.135    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value rs" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:31.137    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value rs" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:31.139    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value rs" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:21:31.141    9596-9596/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter D/FRCRecycleRushPitScouterJSONSerializer﹕ Error: org.json.JSONException: Value rs" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-21 13:26:07.836  12185-12185/org.huntingtonrobotics.frcrecyclerushpitscouter I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (N/A)
        OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.00
        Build Date: 11/12/13 Tue
        Local Branch:
        Remote Branch:
        Local Patches:
```

Here is where I send and read the string:

```
case Constants.MESSAGE_WRITE:
                    byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    // construct a string from the buffer
                    String writeMessage = mConversationJSONString;
                    mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Me:  " + writeMessage);
                    break;
                case Constants.MESSAGE_READ:
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                    String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                    //Log.i(TAG, readMessage);
                    try {
                        mSerilizer.saveBluetoothTeams(readMessage);
                    }catch (JSONException je){
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + je);
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + e);
                    }

                    mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName + ":  " + readMessage);
                    break;
```

And here is part of my Serializer class where I save the teams on the device where the file was sent:

```
//returns string version of json file
    public String getJSONString() throws JSONException, IOException{
        //Build an array in JSON
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        loadTeams();
        for (Team c : mTeams) {
            array.put(c.toJSON());
        }
        return array.toString();
    }

    //load teams from file system
    public Boolean saveBluetoothTeams(String s) throws IOException, JSONException {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {

            //parse the JSON using JSONTokener

            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);

            ArrayList<Team> bluetoothListData = new ArrayList<Team>();

            //build the array of teams from JSONObjects
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                bluetoothListData.add(new Team(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)));
            }
            mTeams.addAll(bluetoothListData);
            saveTeams(mTeams);
            return true;
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            //ignore
            return false;
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + e);
            return false;

        }finally {
            //ensures the underlying file handle is freed up
            if (reader != null)
                reader.close();
        }
    }
```

Full Bluetooth Chat Service Class:
https://github.com/FRCTeam1501/FRCRecycleRushPitScouter/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/huntingtonrobotics/frcrecyclerushpitscouter/bluetoothchat/BluetoothChatFragment.java

Full Bluetooth Chat Fragment class:
https://github.com/FRCTeam1501/FRCRecycleRushPitScouter/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/huntingtonrobotics/frcrecyclerushpitscouter/bluetoothchat/BluetoothChatFragment.java

Comment: Can you show more of the code where you are reading the data? It looks like you are probably getting the message in chunks, then trying to parse those chunks as JSON before you have the complete data.

Comment: @Tanis.7x I posted my classes for sending teams through Bluetooth.  I think you are right that I am getting my message in chunks.  I'm not sure why it breaks the string down into chunks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tanis.7x was correct that I was receiving my data in chunks.  However I could not get the Object Input/Output Stream to work so I used this method:

1. create a few random characters to put at the end of the data you are sending over Bluetooth.

   ```
   //to put on end of string being sent over bluetooth 
   private static final String SUPER_SECRET_PASSWORD = "~~~";
   ```
2. create a string to be the final string that holds all the chunks

   ```
   //for building final string from bluetooth receiver since JSONString was being received in chunks
   private String mFinalString = "";
   ```
3. build string from Bluetooth data but don't process it till it has the random characters at the end of it.

   ```
             if ((mFinalString.substring(mFinalString.length()-SUPER_SECRET_PASSWORD.length()).equals(SUPER_SECRET_PASSWORD))){

                   try {
                       //remove the super secret password from mFinalString
                       mFinalString = mFinalString.substring(0, mFinalString.length()- SUPER_SECRET_PASSWORD.length());
                       //print mFinalString out in the TextView
                       mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName + ":  " + mFinalString);
                       //process mFinalString in the Serializer
                       mSerializer.saveBluetoothTeams(mFinalString);
                       //clear mFinalString
                       mFinalString = "";
                       Toast.makeText(activity, "Teams Received. Please close your app and restart to reload teams.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }catch (Exception e){
                       Log.e(TAG, "ERROR Saving mFinalString: " + e);
                   }
               }
   ```

All of my code for my Bluetooth Fragment Class can be found here:
https://github.com/FRCTeam1501/FRCRecycleRushPitScouter/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/huntingtonrobotics/frcrecyclerushpitscouter/bluetoothchat/BluetoothChatFragment.java

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be that your data is getting chunked, and you are trying to parse those chunks individually.

There are number of ways to approach this problem. One easy way would be to use [`ObjectInputStream`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) and [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) instead of plain `InputStream` and `OutputStream`. The Object stream variants will handle ensuring that you are sending and receiving complete objects, so if you send a String in an output stream, you should get the complete stream back on the other side in the input stream.

Assuming you are sending the JSON as a String (and it is UTF-8 encoded), sending the JSON is as easy as calling `writeUTF(String)`, then reading it using `readUTF()`.