# Object Input/Output Stream causes program to freeze

Tags: android, bluetooth, connection, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I am new to Object Input Streams and Object Output Streams but I have to use them to send a string over Bluetooth.  Whenever I try to make the connection both phones freeze and then crash.  I used the debugger and the last line it stopped at before the program froze is: `tmpIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());`

Here is my connection thread:

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final ObjectInputStream mmInStream;
        private final ObjectOutputStream mmOutStream;
        private FileOutputStream mmFileOut = null;


        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType) {
            Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread: " + socketType);
            mmSocket = socket;
            ObjectInputStream tmpIn = null;
            ObjectOutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams

            try {
                //input stream
                //mmFileIn = new FileInputStream("t.tmp");
                tmpIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                //output stream
                mmFileOut = new FileOutputStream("t.tmp");
                tmpOut.flush();
                tmpOut = new ObjectOutputStream(mmFileOut);
                tmpOut.writeObject(socket.getOutputStream());


            }catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe){
                System.out.println("FileOutPutStream: "+ fnfe);
            }catch (IOException ie){
                System.out.print("ObjectOutputStream: " + ie);
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.print(e);
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost();
                    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                    BluetoothChatService.this.start();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Write to the connected OutStream.
         *
         * @param buffer The bytes to write
         */
        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(buffer);

                // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

I read somewhere it may have to do with using .flush() on my Object Output Stream am I using that correctly?

Answer (score 2):

The code in the constructor runs on the UI thread. Move it to run().

Comment: was correct that I should move my code into run(). However, instead of using ObjectInput/OutputStream this is what I ended up doing:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074603/jsonstring-wont-convert-to-jsonarray